# Use of eval() in local program

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm making a small program with Python and openpyxl. I have created a function and I would like to reuse it according to a conditional, I have seen that eval() can be dangerous for possible exploits of attackers.

But using the eval() method in a local program, where the conditionals are not passed by the user, is it dangerous? do you have any alternative to modify my code and use it the way I want without the use of eval()?

The function have to move the values from one or multiple cols to another col/cols depending on a certain condition.

The function doesn't work now, I want to clarify myself first and then I will write it. I hope you understand what I want to do.

```
def move_values_between_cols(col, condition, col_values_to_change, new_col_values):
    wb = load_workbook(file_path)
    ws = wb.active

    for cell in ws[col]:
        if eval(condition):
            for pos in col_values_to_change:
                ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=new_col_values[pos]).value = cell.value

    wb.save(file_path)
```

Edit:

I receive 4 or 5 different types of excel sheets, all of them with the same information fields but sorted in different ways and some with extra columns. And I need them all with the same shape. I have a function for each type of excel that goes from how it is to how I want it. The condition is written by me.

Example of a function:

```
def type1():
    function1()
    function2()
    move_values_between_cols('A', 'cell.value is None', ['B','C'], ['D', 'F']):

def type2():
    function2()
    function3()
    move_values_between_cols('C', 'not isinstance(cell.value, str)', ['A','B'], ['D', 'F']):
```

Comment: If you know what the string you are passing into eval is and what it will do, then it is exactly as safe as running it would be if it were in code in your source file.

Comment: @khelwood Edited with the eval()

Comment: And where are you getting `condition` from? Why does it need to be a string? Perhaps you could post a [mre].

Comment: I really dont see a problem using eval in this situation.

Comment: It's not always dangerous, but in most cases `eval()` is a crutch used to solve a problem that's more easily and efficiently solved in some other way - it's rarely the best solution to a problem. Where is your condition coming from and what does it actually typically look like?

Comment: @khelwood I receive 4 or 5 different types of excel sheets, all of them with the same information fields but sorted in different ways and some with extra columns. And I need them all with the same shape.
I have a function for each type of excel that goes from how it is to how I want it. The condition is written by me.

Comment: Why don't you write the conditions as functions instead of strings?

Comment: Create one function to evaluate a condition (true / false) and then call that function in the method as parameter and inside the function evaluate if the result of the function is true or false? this is what you mean? @khelwood

Comment: I mean e.g. pass `lambda v: v is None` as a the condition to your function, and then use `if condition(cell.value)` in your function instead of `if eval(condition)`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, is there any way to mark your answer as correct even if it's a comment? @khelwood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is that you pass functions to `move_values_between_cols` instead of strings that need to be evaluated.

For example:

```
move_values_between_cols('A', lambda value: value is None, ['B','C'], ['D', 'F'])
```

and inside `move_values_between_cols`, check the condition with

```
if condition(cell.value):
```

instead of

```
if eval(condition):
```

Comment: Personally, I **still** always find lambdas difficult to read and prefer passing in normal functions.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments you could you lambda-functions instead of strings:

```py
def move_values_between_cols(col, filter_func, col_values_to_change, new_col_values):
    wb = load_workbook(file_path)
    ws = wb.active

    for cell in ws[col]:
        if filter_func(cell):
            for pos in col_values_to_change:
                ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=new_col_values[pos]).value = cell.value

    wb.save(file_path)

def type1():
    function1()
    function2()
    move_values_between_cols('A', lambda cell: cell.value is None, ['B','C'], ['D', 'F']):

def type2():
    function2()
    function3()
    move_values_between_cols('C', lambda cell: not isinstance(cell.value, str), ['A','B'], ['D', 'F']):
```